# Convert Multi value Map to CSV

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot, hashmap

How do we convert multi value map to CSV, i am able to do with the single key - value map. But facing issue with multi value map.
 I do convert key value using this

```
 private String getCSVRow(Set<String> headers, Map<String, String> map) {
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String header : headers) {
        String value = map.get(header) == null ? "" : map.get(header).replace(",", "");
        items.add(value);
    }
    return StringUtils.join(items.toArray(), ",");
}
```

In this if i want to put `Map<String, List<String>>` as i parameter how will i do it?

Answer (score 0):

create a method that will convert `List` to `String`, and call that method from the `for` loop. So your code becomes

```
for (String header : headers) {      
  String value = map.get(header) == null ? "" : generateStringFromList(map.get(header));
        items.add(value);
}


private String generateStringFromList(List<String> list) {
        // create the code here
}
```